# Office 365: Moving outlook calendar events to another user

Tags: office365

I am looking for the best way to move calendar events from one office 365 account to another. I have a user that is leaving the company, and his replacement needs all the calendar events copied over.  My biggest concern is the user has created several attendees, and I do not want new invites going out.

Does anyone have a suggestion on the best approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I know to do this is simply to export the calendar to a file and then import it on the new user's outlook.

[Here is a link on how to export and import the calendar.](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/transfer-outlook-calendar-74348.html)

Comment: Thank you, I will be working is this today and will report back.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you!